# String manipulation, removing a single comma

Tags: php

**UPDATE 1:**

This is how I am attempting to build the string:

```
header('Content-type:application/json');

function getdata($the_query)
{
    $connection = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass') or die (mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db('db_name', $connection) or die (mysql_error());

    $results = mysql_query($the_query) or die(mysql_error());

    $the_data = "{
            \"rss\": {
                \"channels\" : [
                    { 
                        \"title\" : \"".$title."\",
                        \"link\": \"http://www.mycompany.com/external.php\",
                        \"description\": \"company description goes here\",";

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
                        {
                            extract($row);

                            $the_data .= "\"items\" : [
                                {
                                    \"title\": \"".$title."\",
                                    \"link\": \"".$link."\",
                                    \"guid\": \"".$link."\",
                                    \"pubDate\": \"".$date."\",
                                    \"description\": \"".$description."\"
                                } ],";
                        }   

                    $the_data .= "} ]
                }
                 }";

    mysql_close($connection);

    return $the_data;
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a string similar to this:

```
$mystring = "{
      \"rss\": {
        \"channels\" : [
          { 
            \"title" : \"title goes here\",
            \"link": \"link goes here\",
            \"description": \"description goes here\",
            \"items\" : [
              {
                \"title\": \"title goes here\",
                \"link\": \"url goes here\",
                \"guid\": \"id goes here\",
                \"pubDate\": \"data goes her\",
                \"description\": \"description goes here\"
              } ],
            \"items\" : [
              {
                \"title\": \"title goes here\",
                \"link\": \"url goes here\",
                \"guid\": \"id goes here\",
                \"pubDate\": \"data goes her\",
                \"description\": \"description goes here\"
              } ],
            \"items\" : [
              {
                \"title\": \"title goes here\",
                \"link\": \"url goes here\",
                \"guid\": \"id goes here\",
                \"pubDate\": \"data goes her\",
                \"description\": \"description goes here\"
              } ],
         } ]
      }
    }";
```

How do I remove the last comma?

Comment: I can't think of a good easy way because `json_decode()` doesn't tolerate trailing commas. Why is it in there in the first place? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Seems like JSON, could you please reference your source.

Comment: Maybe I am not doing this the best way, but that string (the item section) is in a loop, hence the trailing comma.  What is the correct way of creating json data?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Maybe you could show us how you build that string.

Comment: @Gumbo, will do, just as soon as gedit recovers.  It's just frozen.

Comment: @Gumbo, please see update in original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fixing the error you should fix the cause and don’t insert that last comma in the first place.

The best would be to build the data structure using PHP’s native data types and then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to convert it to a JSON data string:

```
function getdata($the_query)
{
    $connection = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass') or die (mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db('db_name', $connection) or die (mysql_error());

    $results = mysql_query($the_query) or die(mysql_error());
    $channel = array(
        'title'       => $title,
        'link'        => 'http://www.example.com/external.php',
        'description' => 'company description goes here',
        'items'       => array()
    );
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $channel['items'][] = array(
            'title'       => $row['title'],
            'link'        => $row['link'],
            'guid'        => $row['link'],
            'pubDate'     => $row['date'],
            'description' => $row['description']
        );
    }
    mysql_close($connection);
    $data = array('rss' => array('channels' => array($channel)));
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

get the **position** of the reverse of the string first

> stripos(',', strrev($myString))

then you can do whatever you want, replace it, delete it, up to you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you might be approaching it the wrong way.

But if you really want to do it this way, the following will remove the last comma:

```
$mystring = preg_replace("/,(?![^,]*,)/",'',$mystring);
```

Comment: What's the correct way to build json data?  I am doing it the only way I know, i.e. adding to a string using .= then looping through a database to get the bit which loops.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and make it correct when you generate it.

> I am doing it the only way I know, i.e. adding to a string using .= then looping through a database to get the bit which loops

from this comment it looks like you are just building the string yourself.

While in your loop, check which element in the array you are on and don't add the comma (forgive pseudocode nature of example)

```
$string .= item[i];
if($iterator < ($numberofitems-1){$string .=",";}
```

Obviously in your example above you will need to get the number of rows returned and check whether there are more to come on each loop.

Saying that, I would favour building the json with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$pos= strripos($mystring, ",");
$mystring[$pos]=" ";
```

Answer (score 0):

To make as little modification as it is possible (lazy and wrong way) you could change the way $the_data string is created:

```
      $pieces = array();
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
                    {
                        extract($row);

                        $pieces[] = "\"items\" : [
                            {
                                \"title\": \"".$title."\",
                                \"link\": \"".$link."\",
                                \"guid\": \"".$link."\",
                                \"pubDate\": \"".$date."\",
                                \"description\": \"".$description."\"
                            } ]";
                    }   

                $the_data .= implode(',', $pieces);
```

but overall it is better rewrite whole chunk of your code according with answers above with use of  json_encode function.